# Match each value from one column to another column and insert value from third column in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, match

> I want to match each value from column H with column R if it is found then I want to return the value of column Q next to that R.

- Column H contains 72002 records
- Column Q and R contains 4760 each

**> Formula used:**

```
=INDEX($Q$2:$Q$72003,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(R2,$H$2:$H$72003),0))
```

[image: Picture of the data]

> 2nd Picture

[image: Applying the given formula gives this result which is invalid.]

**> Explanation**

Column H has duplicate values while column R has all unique values of column H.

Comment: In `G2`: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Q$2:Q$4761,MATCH(H2,R$2:R$4761,0)),"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the formula to this:

```
=INDEX($R$2:$R$4769, MATCH(H2,$S$2:$S$4769))
```

Also, I sorted columns R and S by alphabetical order A to Z.
And it worked fine.

> New image of the data
> [image: Data is loaded correctly the way I wanted it to be]

Comment: You need to add `,0` as 3rd condition to your `MATCH`-formula to have exact matches. This way it'll return the largest value smaller than the search value if no exact match is found. In your example you're specifically using exact as part of your match, so I reckon you want exact matches only.